# What is the Google+ API for getting all home page feeds?

Tags: c#, google-plus

Can you tell API for Google+ Home page for getting all feeds?

All Api we getting for our profile. I tried

```
  var w = new WebClient();
        Observable
          .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
          .Subscribe(r =>
          {
              deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GooglePlusAuthentication.UserInfo.Thumbnail>>("[" + r.EventArgs.Result + "]");
              UpdateList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r.EventArgs.Result);

          });
        w.DownloadStringAsync(
          new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/"));
```

please suggest how can I get home page API in Google+.